# Designer going to CSS. Fundamental flaws with links in nested centered divs

Tags: css

I want to set up a full width slideshow based on the Design I've prepared. I'm building the page on the Unsemantic CSS framework as I was already familiar with 960 gridsystem (960.gs).

What I'm missing is how to write physically correct HTML & CSS. I don't want to build these unstable workarounded glued pages like most.

I've tried my best to build it but nothing seems to work the way it should. Here is a part of the page where a slideshow should appear.

[image: THIS IS WHAT IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE]

However, it looks like this.

[image: THIS IS WHAT IT LOOKS IN MY BROWSER]

Here's the CCS:

```
<style>

.slide-wrapper{
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;

}

.slide-item{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:white;

}



.slide-img-wrapper{
    position:relative;
}

.slide-img{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;

}

.slide-description{
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:16%;



}
.description-wrapper{

}

</style>

<div id="slide-wrapper">
<div class="slide-item">
<img class="slide-img" src="../villas.praivit/img/lead.jpg" />
<div class="slide-description">
        <p class="location">SWITZERLAND, CERN</p>
        <h1>VILLA PANORAMA</h1>
        <p class="details">Local Time <b>4:10 am</b>, Temperature <b>32F°</b></p>
        <div class="button-1"><a href="#">VIEW VILLA</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to be specific on what you want fixed, because your desired page has many features that your attempted page hasn't attempted. For one, add `display: inline-block;` to that button to keep it from stretching.

Comment: I would suggest getting the layout/positioning done before adding a branded style otherwise you will end up working with bloated CSS. [Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/crtL6j7u/) of how you could create the centered content using [CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Post your html as well

Comment: Hello and thank you for helping. Yes those two were the Issues, the proper technique of centering and the button. Also I don't know why the title "SWITZERLAND" Is so high above the H1... how do you space those elements properly? And above that Image, I would need a 5% opacity black overlay. But Im going to try it by myself. for now.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<div id="slide-wrapper">
<div class="slide-item">
<img class="slide-img" src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-1.jpg" />
<div class="slide-description">
        <p class="location">SWITZERLAND, CERN</p>
        <h1>VILLA PANORAMA</h1>
        <p class="details">Local Time <b>4:10 am</b>, Temperature <b>32F°</b></p>
        <div class="button-1"><a href="#">VIEW VILLA</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


.slide-wrapper{
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;

}

.slide-item{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:white;

}



.slide-img-wrapper{
    position:relative;
}

.slide-img{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;

}

.slide-description{
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:16%;



}
.description-wrapper{

}

.button-1{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #b8955d;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.button-1 a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```